# Unable to PUT comment to Jira with Javascript using REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to update a jira with a new comment through JavaScript.  I can do this all day long with cURL but using javascript is proving more challenging.  I was able to call the Jira API for a GET request for a key so I know my headers/authentication is working.  Problem is my data.  I don't see what I'm doing wrong to format the JSON string with the comment.  Here's what I have so far:

```
$.ajax({
type: "PUT",
url: "https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-113",
dataType: "json",
headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + userCredentials, "Content-Type": "application/json", 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck' },
data: "{\"update\":{\"comment\":[{\"add\":{\"body\": \"Test comment\"}}]}}",
success: function (json) {

  console.log(json)

},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
  console.log(xhr.status);
  console.log(thrownError);
  console.log(ajaxOptions);
}
});
```

I keep getting 400 Bad Request back.  Plus ajaxOptions just returns "error" so I don't have any indication from Jira why it's complaining.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is propably in this line:

```
data: "{\"update\":{\"comment...
```

Get rid of \ and change this to a javascript-object:
data: {"update": "bla bla" ...

I think you just copied over the text from curl.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Yes, the \ were left over from cURL so I got rid of them but that still didn't help me right away.  I also found a simpler way to create a comment using POST and a simpler JSON string of just `{"body": "Comment"}`.  That still gave me a 400 error.  Then I remembered that I need to `JSON.stringify(commentData)` so that was finally accepted and I was able to create a new comment.  Thanks again