# data option is not working properly in jquery ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax request to call some utilities in the PHP script with the data parameter is get from HTML following:

```
function get_jira(){
    var jira = document.getElementById('CR').value ;
    var jira_pre = document.getElementById('JRTEMP').value ;
    var jira_format = jira.match(/[a-zA-Z]{3}\-\d+/); 
    if((jira_format != null)&&(jira_format != jira_pre)){
        var data = {};
        data['jira'] = jira;
        $.ajax({
            url:'request_jirapage.php',    //the page containing php script
            type: "POST",    //request type,
            data: data,
            success: function(result){
                var tp =JSON.parse(result) ;
                console.log(tp);
                document.getElementById('JRTEMP').value = tp.key;
                document.getElementById('CASE').value = tp.fields.customfield_11106;
                document.getElementById('PID').value = tp.fields.customfield_10141;
                //document.getElementById('PW').value = tp.fields.assignee.displayName;
               
            }
        });
        
    }    
}
```

The id 'CR' is an input text box and its value is "AKF-40831" and this function is working as expected (both ajax and PHP script). But when the data of ajax is changed to jira_format as `data['jira'] = jira_format ;`  then the PHP script is not working properly (ajax call to PHP successfully). While the value of jira and jira_format variables is identical.
I tried to search on google but could not get any related information. Or The cause may be related to the data type of them
Console log:
When data['jira'] = jira, I will get the output as:

```
{expand: "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations", id: "994583", self: "http://abc_xyz.com/rest/api/latest/issue/994583", key: "AKF-40831", fields: {…}}
expand: "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations"
fields: {resolution: {…}, customfield_10500: "<div class="panel" style="background-color: rgb(24…n selected below</b>
↵</ul>
↵</p>
↵</div></div>
↵", customfield_10501: null, customfield_10502: null, customfield_10503: null, …}
id: "994583"
key: "AKF-40831"
self: "http://abc_xyz.com/rest/api/latest/issue/994583"
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

And when data['jira'] = jira_format, I get the error as below:

```
VM56:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (validate_form.js:67)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
```

The PHP script:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $jira1 = $_POST['jira'] ;
    if(isset($jira1)){
        $jira_template = "/[a-zA-Z]{3,4}\-\d+/";
        if(preg_match_all($jira_template, $jira1, $matches)){
            $jira = $matches[0][0];
           $user = 'abcxyz';
            $pwd = 'abcxyz';
            $curl = curl_init();
            $url = "http://abc_xyz.com/rest/api/latest/issue/" . $jira;
            // Optional Authentication:
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pwd");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION , CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 80);
            $result = curl_exec($curl);
            $errors = curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            //$res = json_decode($result, true);
            //$case = $res[fields][customfield_11106];.
            //echo json_encode(array("abc"=>$case));
            echo $result;
        
       }
    }
    
    ?>
```

It's failed at line if(preg_match_all($jira_template, $jira1, $matches)).
Note: Value of jira_format and jira is identical. But why the output is different?

Comment: I won't post an answer just yet. But please try object notation by using `data.jira = jira` then post back here with any other errors.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351198/unable-to-put-comment-to-jira-with-javascript-using-rest-api  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068189/post-an-object-as-data-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: *"not working properly"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement

Comment: @GetSet I changed to data.jira = jira and it work fine. But i got the same issue with data.jira = jira_format

Comment: Open console in browser dev tools. As @charlietfl mentions "not working properly" cannot be debugged as its not an actual error message. You can open dev tools then add actual error message to your question.

Comment: I have updated more logs and php code